# Spring Data JPA query parameters not validated at startup

Tags: java, spring, hibernate, jpa, spring-data-jpa

In the past, I swear Spring would validate `@Query` parameters at startup (e.g. `./gradlew bootrun`). However, we just noticed this runtime exception:

```
org.springframework.dao.InvalidDataAccessResourceUsageException: Named parameter not bound : someParamWithTypo
    nested exception is org.hibernate.QueryException: Named parameter not bound : someParamWithTypo
```

For the query:

```
@Query("FROM MyEntity WHERE someField = :someParamWithTypo")
MyEntity search(@Param(name = "someParam") String someParam);
```

Note that the `@Query` references the parameter `:someParamWithTypo` but the proper name of this parameter is `someParam`. Yet the application starts up fine. If I purposely rename `MyEntity` to something invalid, e.g. `MyEnnnntity`, then start-up fails correctly.

---

- Spring Boot: 2.7.1
- Hibernate: 5.6.9

Comment: I don't know how it would have done so before, as it requires a full persistence unit to push the JPQL (or HQL) string to, and then parameters to bind to the query for an exception. I believe it can only validate it can build a query after deploying the persistence unit, not that it can really run.

Comment: Why would it be able to validate that the entity names are correct, but not the parameter names?

Comment: Because it can build the query object after deployment, which gives JPA a chance to parse the query is valid for the entity. I seem to recall Spring doing this for its own generated queries when you don't specify the query string to use, ie findBySomeField(@Param(name = "someParam") String someParam);  criteria queries allow defining a parameter and its type which can be checked against the entity. JPQL queries though only offer setParameter where you pass in the parameter name and an object value, and most providers only validate it on execution anyway.

Answer (score 0):

I think you have to use     @Query(nativeQuery = true , value = "YOUR QUERY")

Comment: Native queries would specifically _not_ be validated.